# handle Text input action new line in text form field

Tags: flutter, dart

how to change `TextInputAction.newLine` to `TextInputAction.done` after Continuous two new line,
i need to exit new line after selected  many Continuous new line

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to use a state variable in a `Stateful` Widget:

```
bool _done = false;
```

Listen to the edited text:

```
TextField(
 onChanged(s) {
   if (s.substring(s.length - 2) == "\n\n") setState(() => _done = true);
   else setState(() => _done = false);
 }
)
```

And change the `TextInputAction` accordingly:

```
TextField(
 onChanged(s) {
   if (s.substring(s.length - 2) == "\n\n") setState(() => _done = true);
   else setState(() => _done = false);
 },
 textInputAction: _done ? TextInputAction.done : TextInputAction.newLine
)
```